Not confident about going for PCB production
I have come up with my own PCB and I now want to go for production. Though I will order very few boards in the first order, it costs me decent amount of money to get a fully assembled PCB. This PCB is made by combining multiple break-out board schematics which were already tested to work with an Arduino which are Arduino Nano, MCP2515 and a MCP4725 DAC modules.
Though I have reviewed my schematic and PCB multiple times, I am not a 100% confident since this is my first ever PCB and I do not want to make mistakes in the ordered PCB.
Can someone please tell me what will be the last min checks, or if someone is kind enough to help me quickly review my PCB, I would be extremely grateful for them.

That's overly general. First of all some problems are not physical PCB problems, but already problems in the schematics. It will likely be useless to say double check everything in the schematics first - if you have a problem there you just don't know if the schematic is correct. Then a PCB is a physical realization of that schematics. You can make a PCB which technically has the same connections as the schematics, but will not work if the physical implementation is not good. We know nothing about your PCB or schematics so there is no checklist that we can give without seeing the design.

Would it be feasible to order just the PCB and assemble a prototype yourself, since they are quite cheap? Even if you don't fully assemble it, you can do mechanical checks and other sanity checks. For me in Australia (PCBs made in China), I would pay more for postage than the PCBs themselves and I usually have them back in 6 working days.

You could outsource (pay a company) to do a review. Depending on complexity and budget this may or may not be an option for you.

It is fine to post schematic, layout, stack-up etc here for general review. What you do need to keep in mind is that almost no PCB ends up correct the first "board spin", even when made by a seasoned EE. Whenever I make time/cost estimations of electronics projects I always assume that there will be at least 2 prototype runs before production. More complex products = more attempts.

it costs me decent amount of money to get a fully assembled PCB But your time isn't free either. Make sure you know the break-even point where your time triple-checking things in advance will cost more than just ordering another PCB run. Also, the boards probably are <$200 total based on your description. That's what, 4-5 hours of cheap contractor engineering time?

I do not want to make mistakes in the ordered PCB Posting this very question already cost >$10 of your time. Those PCBs are cheap in the grand scheme of things, unless your time and effort are free. You actually do want to possibly let an unlikely mistake make it to the PCB. Because, unless you have a good process and experience, you'll spend a lot of time reviewing things, and you'll still miss it, and you'll expend way more time than it would cost to get a 2nd PCB run. Don't miss the forest for the trees.

Make sure you got all the 3D models imported into your EDA, so that you can generate an accurate 3D model of the board and view it for yourself. Make viewing the board in 3D a normal part of your design process. In any decent EDA tool it's a couple keystrokes away. In KiCad, just press Alt-3 in the PCB editor and footprint editor (!). Import the 3D model (usually STEP files) into the mechanical CAD and make sure it fits into the enclosure as well.

Some general advice:

Anything where you defined the footprint yourself — check and double check. A very common and hardest to fix issue is a bad footprint, mostly you then have to make the board again.

Avoid signals on inner layers — if you have a mistake in the design, you can often cut and wire to fix things IF tracks are on the outside.

Use 0R resistors for signal paths that you are not sure of.

It is fine to have too much decoupling — in fact, there is no such thing (OK there IS, see comments below, but it is easy not to fit some caps if you do use too much)! The same for caps used for stability purposes — you don't HAVE to fit them if they turn out to be unneeded.

Err on the side of caution, verging on paranoia. If it can go wrong, it likely will.

It is a prototype. Accept that it probably will not be right first time. If you can get it working, you are doing ok.

Test points, test points, test points (and do not forget ones for ground).

If the board has an odd physical design with perhaps connectors that need to match the enclosure — also check this many times (re-checking on different days is a good idea).

Use the Design Rules Check of you layout software, and preferably use a supplier who runs their own on your gerbers before making your boards.

More good advice below, read and digest.



Interesting statement that there's no such thing as too much decoupling. Of course there is. If you have too much capacitance, regulators may refuse to start up because it takes too long to charge them and they consider it as overload, or you can fail USB compliance tests if the inrush energy exceeds the limit.

ok fair point. But ... I'll give you a dollar every time you see a beginner make that mistake, and you give me one the other way around - deal? ;-)  ... but indeed - you are correct - call it a figure of speech.

For (1): Print out the PCB layout at 1:1 scaling.  Put your components on the printout and check that all the pins line up.  A sheet of paper is far cheaper than a finished PCB for checking fit.

+1 on too much decoupling, but please add the USB Vbus one. I’ve seen that mistake last week here.

I think the point is that sprinkling a bunch of 100nF to 100pF decoupling caps here and there in strategic places won't hurt anyone (except BoM cost).

All new PCBs have mistakes, it's just the nature of human fallibility.
Combining lots of proven breakouts is an excellent way to lull yourself into a false sense of security. Although the first order function might still be OK, the second order interactions between the parts may well bite you.
Post the layout on here. That might help you head off any integration issues.
Our process included a step called LRIP — Low Rate Initial Production — where we would order just 10 PCBs, with only 5 populated with components, and test them to death in production. And that was AFTER the prototype stage! Don't commit to ordering thousands or even hundreds before you've made ten.
There are things you can do to ease the bring up, debug and correction of new boards. Have plenty of test points. Be able to split power rails to be able to isolate parts of the board. Take 'unused' sets, resets, enables through resistors to ground or rail, so that it's easy to drive them during test. Use small value resistors in signal lines between modules so that you can break, monitor, inject signals easily.
Make life easy for yourself, use a 4 layer board. They are barely more expensive than a 2 layer, and infinitely cheaper than the time you spend finding and trying to work round the compromises that a 2 layer board forces you into. Use one internal layer as an unbroken ground plane, and run your signals on outer layers. I'm not a fan of a 'power plane', I like to treat power like I treat signals, and have 3 layers for routing them all, but other people differ. But if you have an unbroken, UNBROKEN, ground plane, and readily accessible signals, you are 90% good.
Good luck.
Did I mention to keep your ground plane intact? Via clearances are inevitable and OK, tracks running through it are a no-no.

Avoid daisy-chain routing.  This is where a net connects multiple pads by going from the center of one pad directly to the center of the next.  Like this:
-----O-----O-----O-----

The problem here is that if you find that you have to isolate the middle pad from the net (for example, to connect it to a different net) this requires two trace cuts to isolate the pad, plus one jumper to reconnect the outer two pads.
A better way is T routing to everything, like this (exaggerated to show the concept):
    O    O    O
    |    |    |
----+----+----+----

Now the center pad can be isolated with a single cut, and the two outer pads remain connected without jumpers.
There can be both physical and electrical reasons why this is not desirable in some situations, but the method can save a lot of time and effort, and greatly improve the reliability and signal quality of the reworked circuits.

This is a good question, because most of us have learned by failure.
@danmcb lists a number of helpful design tips for prototypes, but those are not really the final checks for mistakes before ordering a board.
Board metadata/dfm

Check the board name and version printed on it
Verify all chips have pin 1 markings.
If you print designators, toggle your layers to only to see if you can actually read them when printed.

Tooling

Run ERC/DRC
Check the board matches schematic (not all tools auto-sync)
Check the gerber/odb output in a different tool
Use a PCB fab that has board DFM checks, eg: eurocircuits.

Signals

Check tx/rx
Check all powers are explicitely connected or you have 4-layer with power planes.
Check opamp +/-

Components

Check component/connector polarities and see if the board has markings for them.
(diodes, leds, capacitors, inductors)
Check if your part numbers actually match the footprints.

There are infinite more things to check, especially when including the design itself.
If someone feels like it, add them.

"Check tx/rx" Yeah... although in case of UART, Murphy's Law applies. You will never get them right, no matter how careful you are :)

With modern tools (used properly, and if the footprints are created correctly!) usually the schematics will match the PCB. So have someone review (or review yourself, with fresh eyes, after at least a day or two) the schematic looking for missing connections etc. It's harder to see a mistake in something you created than someone else's work.
Read every IC datasheet and make sure the unused pins, power supply pins, exposed thermal pads under ICs, and so on are dealt with properly. Do not assume the modules you bought from a hobby source were designed properly in the first place. Seek out EVM boards from the manufacturers for unique chips and see what they did. Make sure resistor power ratings are observed.
Any footprint you've not used successfully before (whether you downloaded or made them yourself), assume they could be wrong. Hole size for THT footprints- check and double check with a pair of digital calipers (inexpensive is fine for this purpose). If plated-through holes are made too small, it is a serious issue. Print the PCB out 1:1 and overlay the part with the board printout. Anything such as a USB connector with a board cutout pay particular attention to the mechanical details.
If your tools support 3D view, use that (with 3D body models you create in a CAD program or download) and make sure the pins line up properly in the center of the pads, and parts don't collide- kind of a double check since the model was created independently.
Make sure that pin numbers mapping from schematic to footprint is not mixed up. Mixing up a couple pins on an SC70 or SOT-23 and trying to hack that to get it to function would not be pleasant. A few parts (such as relays) sometimes show parts from the bottom rather than the top, make sure you catch that when you are creating footprints. If certain pins or mechanical features are important, it can help to put markings on the silk screen for the footprint. For example, the active area of an LCD display - that way when you import the PCB into your MCAD package you can see if the active area lines up with the window. Or just for the shaft center of a rotary encoder.
Can you remember (or, better, have you written down) anything you mentally skipped over thinking you'll check it later? Now is the time.
Sometimes it helps to look at net lists which show things like grounds and make sure everything you expect to be there is there. One way to create a problem is to use a slightly different net name such as +V and V+ for what you want to be the same net, and if each net has more than one connection, the DRC probably won't catch it. You can do a similar thing by highlighting nets in the PCB view if your tool supports that.
Some folks like to give each and every net a unique name so that the net lists are human readable and devoid of any references such as N00342.
You can look at each net in the netlist and check it off on a printed version of the schematic.
Double and triple check for dumb things like mixing up D+ and D-, that Tx is connected to the corresponding Rx and not to the other Tx and so on. Knowing what is correct is actually a handicap here.
Double check the  time stamps on the files and make sure you've run DRC after the last changes and are sending the latest files to the fab. Obvious, perhaps, but mistakes can happen.
Consider liberally adding test points and 0Ω jumper resistors and LEDs to help with debugging.
It might not be ridiculous to just order a few blank boards if you've not made a lot of PCBs before. Even if you don't entirely populate and test them you might catch mechanical issues etc. Sort of 1.5 board spins for 1.1x the cost.

Another point: make sure to actually look at the DRC output.  It may seem silly, but I know of at least one time when someone ran a DRC but after having dealt with DRC failures that resulted from not having things set up properly, misinterpreted a "DRC completed" message as implying that the board had passed DRC, rather than merely indicating that the DRC had found all of the information required to do its job (and build a report listing over a dozen missing connections).

@supercat Good point. Also make sure you've enabled all the DRC tests that make sense. It's so configurable on something like Altium you can easily omit important tests.

My experience is that EE love to pour all their love, effort and thoughts into the most complex stuff they can find on the board: switch regulator layout and efficiency, analog/RF layouts, microcontroller pin-outs, high speed signal routing etc etc.
And then forget all about the mundane but equally important things, namely very basic mechanics. Which is by far the most common problem I see on prototype boards. Including:

Connectors do have a pin 1 and that pin is the one as specified by the datasheet, as is the pin-out. Where male and female may have reversed pin-outs. If you are specifying a male connector, make sure that it has the male pin-out and vice versa. Double check, triple check. Do not mirror the pin-out for the 99th time just because the connector is on the bottom side but you view it from above in the EDA.
Mark polarity and pin 1 on all components that have it. Even if component rotation etc will be specified by the P&P files. Sooner or later someone (a human or the p&p machine) will drop a component and then it's very nice if it ends up as intended anyway. Particularly true for connectors and LEDs, that for some reason tend to end up mounted 180° rotated now and then.
The PCBA needs to fit inside its intended enclosure and that includes its components. Components do take up place not just in the X and Y but the Z dimension as well. And they shouldn't sit in places where they are exposed to mechanical stress.
Components do need to get soldered to the PCB and that means no massive heatsinks in the form of pads or holes directly connected to copper pour. Through-hole components in particular cannot get directly tied to copper pour without a thermal relief layout. And the solder and flux don't care if it's a RF connector which needs a solid ground plane for other reasons.
Diverse creative ways to connect signals together depending on configuration, such as jumpers, "solder straps", traces to be cut etc are simply not suitable for production. Think again. SMD resistors that may or may not be mounted by default tends to be the superior solution.
Remember to add/update the correct board revision. Please don't label revision B "A", that is not helpful at all.

And another mundane but frequent source of problems:

All components on your board needs to have a specified, complete and correct part number. And in case of passives, also a value. Perhaps even things like tolerance or voltage/power rating.
It is really nice if the components specified can actually be purchased in the real world, for a reasonable amount & lead time. Have you checked the manufacturer's part status? Have you confirmed that a well-known vendor does not just list it on their web page but also have it in stock?

I think the above make up at least some 80-90% of all board problems I encounter on prototypes.
